# Unexpected token { in wit.js

Tags: node.js, wit.ai

I am testing wit.ai with the samples provided by fb and I am running in to the following error...

```
/mynodeproj/node_modules/node-wit/lib/wit.js:18
  const {
        ^
        SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
        at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

I'm very new to node and wit. I used `Wit = require('node-wit').Wit;` to initialize and installed the node-wit module. Can some one please help?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. I update my Node Version - this works too.
When you APP ist hosted by Heroku (or something similar) you can do this in your

> package.json

add:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.2.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using an older version of node that doesn't support destructuring out of the box. You may try adding `--harmony_destructuring` after the node executable to enable destructuring on older node versions (as [alluded to](https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit#quickstart) in the `node-wit` Quickstart section of their readme).